# Sort before/during identify duplicate values

Tags: python, arcmap

I'm using ArcMap and I'm trying to find (and eliminate) features based on duplicate values.
I found the following code:

```
uniqueList = []
def isDuplicate(inValue):
  if inValue in uniqueList:
    return 1
  else:
    uniqueList.append(inValue)
    return 0
```

and

```
isDuplicate( !FIELD!)
```

which works great, however the problem I have is that its not always identifying the duplicates I want to eliminate. (Some are right, some are wrong.)

If there is a way to sort by another field as part of this code, that would solve the problem.

Is there something I can add to the code above to sort by another field (shape_area smallest to largest)

Obviously I've tried sorting the attribute table first, but it doesn't seem to affect the duplicate code.

Comment: Try physical sort, i.e. sort tool.

Comment: The answer was posted by FelixIP in a comment. by using the Sort(Data Management) it then allowed my python code to flag the smaller-sized duplicates as intended.

Comment: Undelete and accept your own answer please. With some rewording perhaps.